# Why does deleteUI not work in Maya Python with this script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm having some issues with this script I've written in Maya Python! I want to be able to call a function to close the UI by pushing a button. I've looked around both here and on other sites and I can't seem to make it work. Nothing happens when I press the 'Close' button.

```
def closeUI(*args):

    if (cmds.window('mainWindow', exists=True)):
        cmds.deleteUI('mainWindow')


def mainWindow(*args):

    closeUI()

    mainWindow = cmds.window( title="Auto-rig", widthHeight=(300, 300), s=False, vis=True, toolbox=True )
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )

    cmds.button( label='Create Joints (1 of 3)', command=createJoints, en=True )

    cmds.button( label='Create IK (2 of 3)', command=createIk, en=True )

    cmds.button( label='Create Controls (3 of 3)', command=createControls, en=True )

    cmds.button( label='Close', command=closeUI, en=True )

mainWindow()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful with using string references to Maya gui widgets -- you are not guaranteed to get the name you asked for. So even if your code tries to create a window named "X", you may get a window called "X1", and if you've got the reference hard coded you'll never find "X1"

The right way to do it in this case is to capture the name of the window in a variable when it's created, and then use that saved name.  You can do this quite elegantly using a closure: the python feature that allows a function to 'capture' the value of a variable that was present at declaration time.  here's a very basic example, that uses closures and ignores window ids:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def create_window():
    window = cmds.window(title='Main Window')
    column = cmds.columnLayout()
    button = cmds.button("Delete me")

    def close_handler(*_):
        cmds.deleteUI(window) # 'window' is captured by the closure

    cmds.button(button, e=True, command = close_handler)

    cmds.showWindow(window)
    return window

create_window()
```

If you want to remember what the actual id of the main window is, just store the result of 'create_window'.  Given the hassles involved in making sure that you always know the proper path name of hard-coded UI items, its rarely worth the hassle.

You can and should extend the use of the closures to deal with other kinds of communication between bits and pieces of your UI.  Most of the time it's easier and less bug prone than trying to manage it all with hard coded strings.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helps!

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS  WORKING  MAYA  PYTHON  SCRIPT.

[image]

You should not use `def main_Window(*args)` for current script.

```
import maya.cmds as maya

def createJoints(*args):
  print 'createJoints button was pushed.'

def createIk(*args):
  print 'createIK button was pushed.'

def createControls(*args):
  print 'createControls button was pushed.'

def closeWindow(*args):    
  print 'mayaWindow was closed.'

  if (maya.window( mayaWindow, exists=True )): 
    maya.deleteUI( mayaWindow, control=True )  

mayaWindow = maya.window( title="Auto-rig", widthHeight=(300, 300), s=False, vis=True, toolbox=True )
maya.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
maya.button( label='Create Joints...(1 of 3)', command=createJoints, en=True )  
maya.button( label='Create IK...(2 of 3)', command=createIk, en=True )
maya.button( label='Create Controls...(3 of 3)', command=createControls, en=True )
maya.button( label='Close', command=closeWindow, en=True )
maya.showWindow( mayaWindow )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def del_win(win_id, *args)
    if cmds.window(win_id, query=True, exists=True):
       # add type of UI element, window, layout, control
       cmds.deleteUI(win_id, window=True)
window = cmds.window("main_win", title="Auto-rig")

del_win("main_win")
```

or

```
del_win(window)
```

back to your code

```
from functools import partial
def closeUI(win_id, *args):
    if (cmds.window(win_id, exists=True)):
        cmds.deleteUI(win_id, window=True)

def main_Window(*args):

    cmds.window("mainWindow", title="Auto-rig", widthHeight=(300, 300), s=False, vis=True, toolbox=True )
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
    cmds.button( label='Create Joints (1 of 3)', command=createJoints, en=True )
    cmds.button( label='Create IK (2 of 3)', command=createIk, en=True )
    cmds.button( label='Create Controls (3 of 3)', command=createControls, en=True )
    cmds.button( label='Close', command=partial(closeUI, "mainWindow"), en=True )
    cmds.showWindow("mainWindow")
main_Window()
```

Comment: The code works if you just remove the button commands calling functions that doesn't exist. And it actually answers to the question.